# Printer prints black as white and black as white.. why?

Tags: macos, pdf, printing, sonoma

This happens only with PDF files.
Same file if I print from a windows laptop it prints fine.
From MacBook (2021, M1, Sonoma) it will print black as white and white as black. This is on a Canon E 440 printer.

This only happens when I select the "print as greyscale" option. If I print as color, it prints as shown on the screen.

Anyone has any idea why?

Comment: Is it every PDF file, or just some? And not other files in Preview, or from e.g. Pages, Word, etc.?? Have you tried a different PDF reader, like Foxit Reader? Ideally, we'd need a sample to inspect/test. You're sure all the print dialog settings are all correct? What is the printer?

Comment: The printer is a Canon E 440, Word, etc is not creating this problem. I think it is happening with PDFs created from web applications? Here is a sample - LINK REMOVED

Comment: I can't see any problems with the file itself, and its prints OK for me. (You should probably remove it from public view now, as it's a bit personal!) Have you checked the print options? What happens if you Save As PDF from the print menu?